# Removing suggestion box soft keyboard

Tags: android, input, android-softkeyboard

I know this question has been asked multiple times. I've read the majority of them and still have yet to find a solution. What I'm looking for is a way to remove the suggestion box entirely from the soft keyboard.

When the password field is selected everything looks perfect, but if it's the Email field that's selected the suggestions box always pops up and I can't get it to stop.[Image highlighting the exact area I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twH8r.png)

The reason why I want it removed is because it's shifting the size of my view since I have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" included with the manifest. I wanted to do this on my login screen to remove the need for a ScrollView and to have everything placed scrunched up in an easy to find location when the soft keyboard is activated. Everything works perfectly except for when the email field becomes active and displays the suggestion box. Then when you switch to the password field everything gets moved again.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

**activity_emailpassword.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
tools:context=".activity.auth.EmailPasswordActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/login_logo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LoginBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:privateImeOptions="nm"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textWebEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email ID" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="Login" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Create Account"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/create_account_button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/forgot_password_button"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/create_account_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/create_account_button"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Forgot Password?"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml for your layout ? If you auto-generated the layout there might be some autocomplete code. Lastly, are you using a custom keyboard?

Comment: `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` add this to Email field

Comment: @NileshDeokar I added android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" to the email field but that didn't seem to work. I appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by using:

android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"

Not sure if it's the best option, but it does work.